# How to find most frequent substrings in a string using Bash?

Tags: bash, algorithm, combinations, string-algorithm

Please, how to solve the following problem:

How to find the most frequent substrings in a given string? For example the string:

`acd0a55b171241cc13afc7135acd09d609f9e4928e18908e6f6fb5574b4ac13731f993031a13f`

In this string there are substrings `acd0` and `c13`.
Also substring `13` and more.

How to find all appearing substrings ranked by the number of characters in it?

For example:

`acd0`: 4 characters 2 times

`c13`: 3 characters 2 times

`13`: 2 characters 2 times!

Actually `13` appears 4 times but is already twice in `c13` and therefore is not allowed to be counted again.

The solution should be in Bash.

Comment: What have you tried this far? It's commonly expected that questions in StackOverflow show some effort in terms of actual code. So, maybe try some programming on your own, and then ask specific questions concerning parts you have trouble with. Consider putting aside a few minutes to take a look at [some guidelines about asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) too.

Comment: I tried using grep. This only leads to counting and sorting single characters like this:

grep -o . ./string.txt | sort | uniq -c


5640 0


5569 1


5673 2


5896 3


5472 4


5737 5


5950 6


5831 7


5518 8


5563 9


5463 a


5503 b


5791 c


5389 d


5744 e


5499 f



I don't know how to find the combinations automatically.

Answer (score 4):

You need to create the [suffix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree).
It's a tree that contains all repeating substrings of a given string.

The most efficient algorithm for creating suffix tree is [Ukkonen's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukkonen%27s_algorithm)

More info:
[Fast String Searching With Suffix Trees](http://marknelson.us/1996/08/01/suffix-trees/)

There are some implementations of this algorithm on the web for c++ and python.
I'm not sure it would be easy to write this directly in bash but you can try.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I've never heard of suffix trees before.

Comment: If you feel this answer is sufficient you can click `✓` button to accept the answer